# datetimepicker not updating value

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, uidatepicker

I can't update datepicker value

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Date bedut</label>
                      <input type="text" id="picker1" class="form-control" name="dateD">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Date fin</label>
                      <input type="text" id="picker2" class="form-control" name="dateF">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

$("#picker1").datetimepicker({
          timepicker: true,
          datepicker: true,
          format:'Y-m-d - H:i',
          onShow: function(ct){
            this.setOptions({
              minDate: $("#picker2").val() ? $("#picker2").val(): false
            })
          }
        })
      $("#picker2").datetimepicker({
          timepicker: true,
          datepicker: true,
          format:'Y-m-d - H:i',
          onShow: function(ct){
            this.setOptions({
              maxDate: $("#picker1").val() ? $("#picker1").val(): false
            })
          }
        })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mazgour Aziz

Please try this code for datetimepicker :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css"> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' value="11/06/2019 11:13 AM" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
          </div>
       </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use input type="date"

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Date bedut</label>
          <input type="date" id="picker1" class="form-control" name="dateD">
     </div>
</div>
```